# mariadb does not optimize the execution order for 'left join'

Tags: sql, mariadb, left-join, query-optimization

with a  mariadb-server-10.3.9 database, there're about 500,000 rows in table 'log_api'.

it cost 1.44s if the sql written as a plain `left join` sql:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.client_ip,
       a.api_address,
       a.deleted,
       a.create_date,
       a.update_staff,
       a.update_date,
       a.remark,
       a.timestamp,
       a.instance,
       a.msg_data,
       c.project_name,
       d.service_name AS fw_server_name,
       e.agent_name
FROM log_api a
         LEFT JOIN wb_project c ON c.project_code = a.project_code
         LEFT JOIN fw_service d on d.service_code = a.service_code
         LEFT JOIN wb_agent e ON e.agent_code = a.agent_code
where a.deleted = 0
  and timestamp >= '2023-06-05T00:00:00'
  and timestamp
    < '2023-06-07T00:00:00'
order by timestamp desc
limit 100 offset 10000;
```

but it only needs 0.02s if the sql write as a embedding query sql:

```
select m.id,
       m.client_ip,
       m.api_address,
       m.deleted,
       m.create_staff,
       m.update_staff,
       m.update_date,
       m.remark,
       m.timestamp,
       m.instance,
       m.msg_data,
       c.project_name,
       d.service_name AS fw_server_name,
       e.agent_name
from (SELECT a.id,
             a.custom_service_order_code,
             a.service_code,
             a.project_code,
             a.agent_code,
             a.user_name,
             a.client_ip,
             a.api_address,
             a.deleted,
             a.create_staff,
             a.create_date,
             a.update_date,
             a.remark,
             a.timestamp,
             a.instance,
             a.msg_data
      FROM log_api a
      where a.deleted = 0
        and timestamp >= '2023-06-05T00:00:00'
        and timestamp
          < '2023-06-07T00:00:00'
      order by timestamp desc
      limit 100 offset 10000) m
         LEFT JOIN wb_project c ON c.project_code = m.project_code
         LEFT JOIN fw_service d on d.service_code = m.service_code
         LEFT JOIN wb_agent e ON e.agent_code = m.agent_code
```

Nearly all sql performance tuning guideline propose to avoid embeding query sql, as the database engine will have more change to to optimize with a plain sql. anyone can confirm is this a bug in mariadb or I used a too old version of mariadb?

Comment: MIght have to do with `limit 100 offset 10000`. In your first example you are limiting the end result of the query (so joins are performed on the full log_api table), in the second you start out with a smaller sample of the log_api table and then perform the joins?

Comment: Will the second query even parse?  Can you have an order by in a derived table?

Comment: @Andrew Yeah, don't think that's a problem

Comment: note that mariadb 10.3 has reached end of life and should be considered insecure; you should upgrade to 10.6 or 10.11.

Comment: please update your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table log_api` and `explain select ....rest of your query` for both selects

Comment: that said, doing pagination in a subquery is often a good thing.  if you like to depend on internet advice, search for "deferred join pagination" to find pages recommending this.  do note if you want results ordered by timestamp you need an order by in your outer query too, since order in the subquery is not guaranteed to have any effect on the output rows

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT whatever FROM something-complex ORDER BY col LIMIT n` is a notorious query-performance antipattern. Why?

It has to create an intermediate result set doing the JOINs, the sort it, then discard all but a tiny bit of it. It's even worse with a large OFFSET: it has to go through the sorted result set discarding all those OFFSET rows before it can return the tiny result set.

Your second sample query is faster because it only has to do that stuff on one table. And, it may be faster still because you have an index on that `timestamp` column you use in your ORDER BY clause. (You didn't show us the table definition.)